# How does the computer know that the word ‘letter’ is the letter that we know?

Tags: python

in the following code:

```
 fruit='banana'
 for letter in fruit:
       print(letter)
```

How does the computer know that the word ‘letter’ is the letter that we know? because we haven’t defined anything then How can python print the letters of banana?

Comment: _"we haven’t defined anything"_ - you defined _everything_, you said "iterate over this string (`fruit`) and assign each character in turn to the name `letter`".

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp

Comment: Does `for letter in "banana"` make more sense? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, ypu can put whatever you wanted instead of "letter", youcould have put just a single letter and it would work. In this loop, the computer is assigning a variable called "letter" for each letter in your word and reading it. Name doesn't matter as long as you have put some kind of value.

Answer (score -1):

The computer reads an entire line (up to the `:` point). Also, the program you demonstrated said "iterate over the word banana and print each letter out". The `for letter in fruit` itself declares a variable, otherwise, you might get a `SyntaxError`. Python code itself is easy to parse, and for loops and its content might be written in a single line.

Comment: Please keep answers respectful.